# podfile.lock is missing from working copy

Tags: xcode7, cocoapods, ios10, podfile

I recently started having this issue after attempting to use the `pod update` command on my project. After successfully updating the pods, xcode now gives me the following error

"podfile.lock is missing from working copy"

Now i have tried cleaning the build, deleting derived data, updating cocoapods but this doesn't seem to fix the issue. When i look in the commit window the file does not appear to exist in the local version.

Does anyone know a way to sort this?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. In my case in the commit window Podfile.lock(!) and Manifest.lock(?) files were unchecked as shown below,

[image: Podfile.lock(!)]

[image: Manifest.lock(?)]

The content of Podfile.lock(!) file seems carried to Manifest.lock(?) file. I checked both and then pushed to my repository. Afterwards, the warning was gone and I had no issue related to Pod. Hope you can solve your issue by doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

Let me c .It's a really general question.
The reason is that your project use the git/svn to manager.And you change your coding without commit.So you just commit your project.And you will find warning disappear.

Thanks